# how to redirect all the laravel 5.4 url to https instead of http on AWS

Tags: .htaccess, amazon-web-services, web-config, laravel-5.4, php-7.1

I followed many solutions from stackoverflow but that didn't solved my issue:-

the Laravel Redirect URLs are not going on HTTPS, 
in ENV file:
 `APP_URL=https://sub-domain.myweb.nyc` 
also i have putted it in config\app.php `'url' => env('APP_URL', 'https://qa-web.myweb.nyc'),` ... need help, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

```
RewriteEngine On

# Redirect to https
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

This worked for me...

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in the .htaccess file on your public folder. Try to do this:

```
# Force SSL
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```